# How do I map Vim colon search and replace command to work just with visual selection?

Tags: vim, neovim

Sometimes I want to replace some text in multiple lines but not in the whole line, so I toggle visual mode on and highlight the text I want to replace. But then, I need to add this annoying `\%V` that I always forget for it to replace the text just in the selection and not in the whole line

```
:'<, '>s/\%Vold/new/g
```

Is there a way to map the normal replace command

```
:'<, '>s/old/new/g
```

To the one shown above so that I don't need to remember that V every time?

Thank you

I tried using cmap command in the vimrc file in the following way:

```
cmap '<, '>s/* '<, '>s/\%V*
```

But this of course doesn't work, because instead of the asterisk I should input the text I want to search and replace to end the search and replace command.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic parts to a mapping:

- the mapping command,
- the "left-hand side" (LHS),
- and the "right-hand side" (RHS).

The LHS is the key sequence/combination that you want to press and the RHS is a different key sequence that you want Vim to "press" instead of those in the LHS. You "map" one key sequence to another.

The RHS is, fundamentally, a macro: a sequence of keystrokes, "just" like if you pressed them yourself but without any delay between them. So, the RHS is really just a bunch of keystrokes you are tired of making over and over again.

The main use of mappings is to reduce repetitiveness. You figure that you often press the imaginary sequence `sdlusdrosydtsodsd` and you map it all to `<F5>` to be more efficient.

In this case…

- The current mode is visual mode so the mapping has to be a visual mode mapping.

  *This makes `:xmap` or `:xnoremap` the proper mapping command*. Let's make it `:xnoremap`.
- The repetitive key sequence you want to abstract away is:

  ```
   :s/\%V
  ```

  *That's your RHS*.

  (Note that the range `'<,'>` is automatically inserted for you so it can be ignored.)
- The key sequence you want to press instead is, let's say… `<F5>`.

  *That's your LHS*.

Now that you have your mapping command, your LHS, and your RHS, building the mapping is extremely easy:

```
:xnoremap <F5> :s/\%V
```

[image: xmap]

Comment: Note that the value of this answer doesn't reside in the snippet at the end *at all*.